# Threading in WCF and Dependency Property (The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it exception)

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf

Any help will be very appreciated.

We have a WCF service (hosted in IIS) that is calling a method, and inside this method there is a call to a getter of a dependency property (this getter is part of of several dependency properties gathered in a single object and used for all kind of conversions).

We see sometimes, and not consistent, a crash on the WCF service side, with the following exception message:

"**The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it**".

I did some searching and found out a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267943/the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-different-thread-owns-it).

From the reading I understand that there is a scenario in which the getter is called on a different thread, and this is why we don't see this exception all the time.

However, I'm still puzzled about the solution. Does the WCF service has a dispatcher on which I can activate CheckAccess() and then call the Dispatcher.Invoke() method (like in WPF application)?

Can someone please advise?

Thanks,

Elad

Comment: Why are you using a `DependencyObject` from within IIS?  That's the root problem here - `DependencyObject` classes, in general, are never intended to be used outside of a system with a proper `Dispatcher`.

Comment: I thought that dependency properties were WPF specific? Is this also an WPF app?

Comment: This is not a WPF application. This is a WCF service using some kind of an infrastructure contains set of objects, and several of them are exposing dependency properties. We have inherited this infrastructure and needs to use it.

Comment: You're referencing a WPF assembly in a WCF service hosted in IIS?

Comment: @EladGutman well then, as  Reed Copsey says, looks like the solution is fundamentally flawed, the best bet is to redesign your app not to use technologies in the way they are not supposed to be used, and if this fails write you own thread synchronization code (which is complicated and error prone). WCF does not have a Dispatcher.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments and the advises. We'll see how we can continue from here.

Answer (score 0):

ALL DependencyObjects have thread-affinity. They can only be accessed by the thread that instantiated it. Call DependencyObject.CheckAccess() to determine if on correct thread.
Here's an example. Even though the code uses a Button, a Button is still a DependencyObject.

```
private void TryToUpdateButtonCheckAccess(object uiObject)
{
    Button theButton = uiObject as Button;

    if (theButton != null)
    {
        // Checking if this thread has access to the object
        if(theButton.CheckAccess())
        {
            // This thread has access so it can update the UI thread
            UpdateButtonUI(theButton);
        }
        else
        {
            // This thread does not have access to the UI thread
            // Pushing update method on the Dispatcher of the UI thread
            theButton.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                new UpdateUIDelegate(UpdateButtonUI), theButton);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Steven, thanks a lot for the example. I'm familiar with this pattern in WPF and I thought there is something similar in WCF in case we "combine" dependency properties.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a class in your "primary" thread which inherits from [DispatcherObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject.dispatcher.aspx).  That will give you access to the Dispatcher property in WCF.

Answer (score 0):

Since your problem is to do with accessing dependency properties across multiple threads, you could use an STA threading model in your WCF service.

This article describes the approach

http://www.netfxharmonics.com/2009/07/Accessing-WPF-Generated-Images-Via-WCF

The relevant section is near the end of the article. It sounds like he is describing your exact problem.